# Cannot understand why fprintf() doesn't work here

Tags: c, file

Cannot understand `fprintf()`. I need to rewrite data in .txt file but it doesn't work. Problem is in `void fileEdit` function. After I write new number for 'wT', 'wF' or 'nap' it saves only in `while (whT)` loop and doesn't want to go further.
[Full code with .txt file](https://pastebin.com/ekyarU4Q)

```
void fileEdit(FILE **file) {
    int dayEdit = 0;
    int playerChoose = 0;
    float nap = 0.0, wF = 0.0, wT = 0.0;
    while (true) {
        int day = 0;
        bool whT = true;
        system("CLS");
        printFile(file);
        printf("Which day you want to edit[1 - 31, 0 to exit]: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &dayEdit);
        if (dayEdit == 0)
            break;
        while (day < dayEdit) {
            fscanf_s(*file, "%d %f %f %f", &day, &wF, &wT, &nap);
            printf("\n %d ", ftell(*file));
        }
        while (whT) {
            system("CLS");
            printf(" \n\n -------------------------------\n|      Job Hours Managment     
 |\n -------------------------------\n| Day |  From  |  Till  |  Nap  |");
            printf("\n -------------------------------\n| %3d | %6.1f | %6.1f | %5.1f |", day, wF, wT, nap);
            printf("\n");
            printf(" -------------------------------\n");
            printf("\nWhat you want to edit?[1 From, 2 Till, 3 Nap, 4 Save]: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &playerChoose);
            switch (playerChoose) {
            case 1:
                printf("\nWorked from: ");
                scanf_s("%f", &wF);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\nWorked till: ");
                scanf_s("%f", &wT);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nNap: ");
                scanf_s("%f", &nap);
                break;
            case 4:
                whT = false;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        fprintf(*file, "%d %f %f %f\n", day, wF, wT, nap); // <---- Here i want to save new data
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just deleted my answer because I noted that the length specifiers are interpreted differently for `scanf` (which I never use) and `printf`.

Comment: You have gone from read with `fscanf_s(*file, ...` to write with `fprintf(*file, ...` without an intervening call to a file positioning function.

Comment: Please see [`fopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) *...when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there's no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are `fsetpos`, `fseek`, and `rewind`. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either `fflush` or to a file positioning function.*

Comment: Generally, you can _not_ rewrite free form text files using just a single file. So, you may need to copy to a temp file and back. Also, `%f` is like `%.6f` so if you start with `0.0` as a field and change it to 6, you'll get `6.000000` instead of `6.0` so it will not align as you think it will In fact, it can _not_ work. If you change a field to 12, it can _never_ align as you have it. You _must_ use two files.

Comment: _Side note:_ The double star pointer for `FILE` isn't required. All your functions can be just `FILE *file` instead of `FILE **file` and you can change `*file` into [just] `file`.

Comment: regarding: `float nap = 0.0, wF = 0.0, wT = 0.0;`  This is trying to pace doubble values into float variables/ Suggest: `float nap = 0.0f, wF = 0.0f, wT = 0.0f;` note the trailing `f` to declare float values rather than double values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not appropriate for text files: rewriting some data in the middle of the file does not *insert* the data, it overwrites whatever contents is already there and text conversion of numbers typically may use more or fewer digits than existing contents, so the rest of the file is either corrupted or leaves some stray bytes that prevent proper parsing.

There are different options:

- you can load the whole file in memory, update the contents in memory, and write the updated file version as a new file, then if writing completed without errors, the old file can be removed and the new file can be renamed to the old name.
- you can copy the old file to a new file, updating appropriate contents on the fly, and perform the same renaming scheme at the end
- you can use a fixed length file format, most likely a binary format, and update only the parts that need to be changed. To switch from reading to writing and vice versa to and from the same `FILE *`, you must issue a positioning request: `fseek()` or `rewind()`. To write the updated contents, you must set the file position appropriately at the start of the target area.